# Pubnub - How to UnPublish from a channel

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I tried implementing Pubnub - ["Realtime Flight Tracking Map" example](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/map/flight/)

Can anyone please tell me how to unpublish from a channel and then the corresponding marker should disappear from map.
For example in the demo shown in the link above if a flight "66e234a" goes offline then is marker should not show in map.

Please help me implement this feature..

Comment: This can be added as a feature request here: https://github.com/pubnub/eon/issues/new - `New Feature` **"All ability to remove marker on map"**.  For now you can post a LAT/LONG of `0.0`, `0.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once published you wouldn't want to un-publish the message, just add a status attribute to the data being published such that you can decide to remove, not render or change the marker based on the flight status.

The demo is not demonstrating that type of functionality. You have two options from the PubNub side.

1. Add an attribute to your payload that indicates the current state of the flight. This way you could move the marker, or remove the marker depending on the state of the flight. On the right side code panel

```js
PUBNUB.publish({
    channel:  'sfo-flight-data',
    message:  
      {
        66e234a: {
           latlng: [
             37.6271,
             -122.3858
           ],
           data: [
             "A33D8C",
             37.6271,
             -122.3858,
             118,
             0,
             23,
             "3765",
             "F-KSJC3",
             "DC10",
             "N308FE",
             1433383239,
             "SFO",
             "MEM",
             "FX1345",
             1,
             0,
             "FDX1345",
             ,0
             "active" //ADDED
           ],
         },
         //...
      }
});
```

on the left, the code rendering the marker when a message is received.

```js
  var map = eon.map({
  id: 'map',
  mb_id: 'ianjennings.lec06po7',
  mb_token: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaWFuamVubmluZ3MiLCJhIjoiZExwb0p5WSJ9.XLi48h-NOyJOCJuu1-h-Jg',
  channel: 'sfo-flight-data',
  rotate: true,
  history: true,
  marker: function (latlng, data) {

    if(data[15] !== 'active'){ //EVALUATED
       return;
    }

    var marker = new L.RotatedMarker(latlng, {
      icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: '/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/airplane.png',
        iconSize: [24, 24]
      })
    });

    var popup = '';
    if(data[13]) {
      popup = 'Flight ' + data[13] + '';
    }
    if(data[11]) {
      if(!popup.length) {
        popup = 'Flight from ' + data[11];
      } else {
        popup += ' from ' + data[11];
      }
    }
    if(data[12]) {
      if(!popup.length) {
        popup = 'Flight to ' + data[12];
      } else {
        popup += ' to ' + data[12];
      }
    }
    if(!popup.length) {
      var popup = 'No data available';
    }

    marker.bindPopup(popup);

    return marker;
  }
});
```

The general idea is to react to the changing state of the flights.

Answer (score 0):

## UnPublish and Remove a Marker

Does it work if you set flight to `0.0` and `0.0`?

```
66e234a: {
       latlng: [
         0.0,
         0.0
       ]
```

However ability to `unpublish` "remove a marker from map" can be added as a feature request here: https://github.com/pubnub/eon/issues/new - `New Feature` **"All ability to remove marker on map"**.  For now you can post a LAT/LONG of `0.0`, `0.0`.